# css width attribute giving different outputs for different elements

Tags: html, css

I gave the same width for 2 elements , one is a input text field of a form , other is a div. But they both render different widths when displayed. input field appears to be more wider than the div element. Can someone explain me how to fix it? Is there some fixed proportion by which input field shows more width? Help me.

Comment: This might be because of inputs field's border as divs by default don't have border.

Answer (score 2):

use :

```
input
{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sPN5N/)